# Why am I getting "The name x does not exist in the current context"?

Tags: c#, scope

I'm getting the following error:

> Error 1   The name 'myList' does not exist in the current context

Code is as following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<string> myList = new List<string>();
            myList.Add("Dave");
            myList.Add("Sam");
            myList.Add("Gareth");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string item in myList)
            {
               listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's a very simple example and a real world application would make more us out of classes, but I don't understand why the button1_click event hander can't see the array list.

Comment: Where is the declaration of the 'listView1' list?

Comment: @superpuccio - The listView1 list is just a control I've dragged onto a Form. Do I need to declare it as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comments above the error is: "The name 'myList' does not exist in the current context", right? The problem is that `myList` is declared inside the `form1()` method and you are trying to access it from another method (the `button1_click()` method). You must declare the list outside the method, as an instance variable. Try something like:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<string> myList = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myList = new List<string>();
            myList.Add("Dave");
            myList.Add("Sam");
            myList.Add("Gareth");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string item in myList)
            {
               listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```